# Frequent internet disconnects

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, fios

We now have 6-10 internet connects a day that last for anywhere from 2 to 7 minutes and I wonder if something on my network is causing the problem, but I don't know how to figure it out.

We have Verizon FIOS and have had a new ONT and router installed. Which did not fix the issue.
It affects both wifi and wired connections.

Is there something I can run that shows me what is going on across the network when the connection drops? Maybe a particular device is doing something crazy?

Comment: When I had this problem it was caused by an extremely sensitive firmware and EMI on the line.  In other words, your isp, will have to find the source of the EMI

Comment: How is your router wired to the ONT? Is it being  delivered via Coax or Ethernet to the router? Other than ONT issues which you have indicated it, and the router were just replaced. Would lead me to believe you have an inside wiring issue. Let us know how the router is being fed it's wan from the ONT.

Comment: Coax from the ONT to the router. No splitters.

Comment: So you are saying there are no set top boxes? Just a straight rg-6 coax going from ONT to router. Is this an actiontec mi424wr router or one you supplied? If it's an actiontec what is the revision letter that's labeled on the underside sticker?